# Program only reading 6 out of 15 ints from a file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When reading from a .data file my program will only read 6 out of 15 numbers, but when it reads from a .txt file it will read all the numbers. I need it to read all of the 15 numbers from the .data file.

Here is the code:

```
string PromptUser(void)
{ 
    ifstream infile;
    string filename; 
    cout << "Please enter a file name:" << endl;
    getline(cin, filename);
    while (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a file name:" << endl;
        getline(cin, filename);
    }
    return filename;
}

int ReadData(vector<int>& theData, ifstream& in)
{
    int value;

    if (in.is_open())
    {
        while (in >> value)
        {
            theData.push_back(value);
        }

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

void ComputeStats(vector<int>& theData, double& mean, double& median)
{
    double num = 0; 
    for (int val : theData)
    {
        num = num + val;
    }  
    if (theData.size() != 0)
    {
        mean = num / theData.size();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "yeee" << " " << theData.size();
        exit(0);
    }
    int num2 = 0;
    sort(theData.begin(), theData.end());
    if (theData.size() % 2)
    {
        median = theData[(theData.size() / 2) + 1];
    }
    else
    {
        median = (theData[theData.size() / 2] + theData[theData.size() 
       /2])/2: 

     }

 }

void DisplayStats(int num, double mean, double median)
{
    cout << "********** Data Summary **********" << endl;
    cout << "Number of Values:   " << num << endl;
    cout << "Mean Value:         " << mean << endl;
    cout << "Median Value:       " << median << endl;
    cout << "**********************************" << endl;

}

int main()
{
    vector<int> theData;
    string filename;
    ifstream infile;

    filename = PromptUser();
    infile.open(filename);

    int rtn = ReadData(theData, infile);

    if (ReadData(theData, infile) == 1)
    {
        cerr << "The file could not be open " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    infile.close();

    int numValues = theData.size();
    double meanValue, medianValue;

    ComputeStats(theData, meanValue, medianValue);

    DisplayStats(numValues, meanValue, medianValue);

    return 0;
}
```

the .data file contains the numbers 23, 45, 9, 1, 09, 24, 23, 45, 81, 24, 9, 13, 9, 86, and 12. And the .txt file contains the same numbers. But the program says the size of the .data file is only 6 while it says the .txt file is 15. I need it to read the .data file right for a class I am in.

Comment: Hint: what does `getline()` actually do? How do your two files differ?

Comment: The getline()is just there to get the file name I'm pretty sure. @jdv

Comment: *And the .txt file contains the same numbers.* My guess is that they don't. There is some difference between the files. It's hard telling unless you post the contents of the files.

Comment: @vgiggy, all right, but think about what _is_ reading the file? Since we don't know what the files are, who knows. I'm pointing out that line-oriented files may give interesting results different from non-line-oriented files. Some debugging would probably show the issue.

Comment: ifstream doesn't discriminate between file names and extensions. Your files have different contents. My best guess is that the .data file has more `newline` characters

Comment: @RSahu I posted what is in both files exactly at the very bottom of the post and I am sure they have the exact same numbers.

Comment: @vgiggy, do you expect them to be identical byte for byte? If you do, you can read the contents of the files byte by byte simultaneously, compare each byte, and figure out where they are not identical.

Comment: @GillBates I made both files have the exact same format and same numbers.

Comment: @RSahu I'mm not sure how to do that

Comment: @vgiggy If you are on Linux or Mac, use the terminal `cp` command to copy the contents of one file to the resulting file.

Comment: @GillBates I'm on windows

Comment: @vgiggy Try renaming your `.txt` file to `.data`, and run your program again. I would be very very surprised if it doesn't behave as the initial `.txt`.

Comment: @GillBates I ended up redownloading the file and now it works for the .data file so I don't know what was wrong.

Comment: This is why the od command is so useful. You could have easily tested that your two files were not the same which would have saved you a bunch of headache. Always test your assertions!